Charged plate between two different dielectrics
Imagine a charged plate, placed in between two DIFFERENT dielectrics of susceptibilities $\chi _1\:and\: \chi _2$ .

From Gauss's law, We can conclude that the sum of the magnitude of the electric displacements $D_1\:and\:D_2$
is equal to the free surface charge density.
$$D_1 + D_2 = \sigma_f$$

Gauss's law alone cannot determine $D_1\:and\:D_2$ because there is two variables with only one equation.
But instead, If we had used Gauss's law for E and bound charges, we will arrive at $D_1=D_2=\frac{\sigma_f}{2}$ .
The results imply that the electric displacement is symmetric for both sides of the plate, however, the dielectric between two plates are not of the same kind, so we can not simply state that they are the same.
My question is, in which case can we use symmetry of the problem? (other than the obviously symmetric one with the same dielectric on both sides, or spherical, cylindrical etc.)

The question is not really related to the presence of those dielectric materials. You could ask the same for just a conductive plate between two empty half spaces of pure vacuum.
And there is absolutely no way to know the individual $E$-field values to the left and the right of that plate, only the sum of the two outward $E$-fields is known to equal the charge density $\sigma$. Only with some extra information about those fields, can we determine the complete solution. It is simply not justified to assume a priori that the solution should be symmetric. (After all, there could be a second plate somewhere, parallel to our first one, and then "symmetric" would get a different meaning and the symmetric solution would have ${\bf E}=0$ on one side of our plate.)
Nevertheless, if for whatever reason we do want to find a symmetric solution for the case described, the most natural concept of "symmettric" would be equal field strength left and right of the total layer stack, so left of the layer $\sigma_{\large b_1}$ and right of $\sigma_{\large b_2}$, because those are the boundary conditions to the outside world and they should give us the extra information we need.

But if I had used Gauss's law with bound charges, and superposition principle. I would've gotten the answer. This makes me feel like I could also apply superposition principle to determine the NORMAL component of D too. Am I correct with this reasoning? And when can't I use superposition?

No you would not, with Gauss' law you can get any solution with different fields left and right. Where you write: "If we had used Gauss's law for E and bound charges", you do not know a priori what the bound charges are. (You can change the left/right ratio there as well; just assuming some equal division is the same arbitrariness as with the first approach, you still have only one equation with two unknowns.)

With different permittivities for the two dielectrics, the only symmetry left is the symmetry present in the geometry, i.e. equal thickness of the two dielectric slabs. The geometric symmetry will tend to make the solution look nicer.
When it comes to actually solving the problem, the issue at hand here is not that there is a lack of symmetry, but rather that the problem is under-determined - there are not enough boundary conditions. The problem could become fully determined by, for example, placing a grounded plate on the outward facing surface of each dielectric.
